# Heroku Application Error when using Heroku create command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, sqlite3-ruby

I am following a tutorial at http://onemonth.com where I created my rails app. I was asked to use **Heroku** to get my app live online. I followed the steps for linking my **Github** account to **Heroku** via the SSH key. 
However when I use the command `heroku create` and then copy past the link provided, in this case http://young-peak-7631.herokuapp.com/, I get an "Application Error" in the browser.

This is the exact message:

"An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.If you are the application owner, check your logs for details."

**See picture of Heroku error page below**
[image]
**Here is my logs:**

```
       2014-07-01T06:50:55.157229+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.7ms)
2014-07-01T06:50:56.211672+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/about" host=omr-photoshare.herokuapp.com request_id=0b8e9a43-5ffd-4bae-aa4f-61e9f87dfdfc fwd="65.78.4.236" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=192ms status=304 bytes=845
2014-07-01T06:50:56.025883+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/about" for 65.78.4.236 at 2014-07-01 06:50:56 +0000
2014-07-01T06:50:56.082614+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/about.html.erb within layouts/application (0.2ms)
2014-07-01T06:50:56.174581+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 95ms (Views: 7.0ms | ActiveRecord: 86.8ms)
2014-07-01T06:50:56.079586+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#about as HTML
2014-07-01T06:50:56.173874+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (90.3ms)
2014-07-01T06:50:57.026362+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/edit" host=omr-photoshare.herokuapp.com request_id=9e7dbd9b-1e90-4cf0-b422-a39fc4dd86af fwd="65.78.4.236" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=26ms status=200 bytes=4509
2014-07-01T06:50:57.023820+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (6.5ms)
2014-07-01T06:50:57.007189+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/edit" for 65.78.4.236 at 2014-07-01 06:50:57 +0000
2014-07-01T06:50:57.027133+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 12.8ms | ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
2014-07-01T06:50:57.010704+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#edit as HTML
2014-07-01T06:50:57.026562+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.5ms)
2014-07-01T06:50:58.037348+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users/sign_out" host=omr-photoshare.herokuapp.com request_id=62ed2279-f63e-4c4f-9721-7b1361348276 fwd="65.78.4.236" dyno=web.1 connect=32ms service=41ms status=302 bytes=931
2014-07-01T06:50:58.138958+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=omr-photoshare.herokuapp.com request_id=d36b09ab-feb9-4e13-8b07-97bda734f4cd fwd="65.78.4.236" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=72ms status=200 bytes=2809
2014-07-01T06:50:58.004542+00:00 app[web.1]: Started DELETE "/users/sign_out" for 65.78.4.236 at 2014-07-01 06:50:58 +0000
2014-07-01T06:50:58.034982+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 25ms (ActiveRecord: 12.2ms)
2014-07-01T06:50:58.119933+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2014-07-01T06:50:58.137550+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.5ms)
2014-07-01T06:50:58.009338+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#destroy as HTML
2014-07-01T06:50:58.116047+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 65.78.4.236 at 2014-07-01 06:50:58 +0000
2014-07-01T06:50:58.009357+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"5AnEyKY75EbCUcrc50OZjx2MOguNlKFceSaDg5DoFzw="}
2014-07-01T06:50:58.136033+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (14.2ms)
2014-07-01T06:50:58.034741+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://omr-photoshare.herokuapp.com/
2014-07-01T06:50:58.138057+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 18ms (Views: 16.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-07-01T06:51:00.169842+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/sign_in" host=omr-photoshare.herokuapp.com request_id=102f1369-f2c7-4c60-95fd-fdcf94c91f3b fwd="65.78.4.236" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=95ms status=200 bytes=3735
2014-07-01T06:51:00.148527+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 65.78.4.236 at 2014-07-01 06:51:00 +0000
2014-07-01T06:51:00.163967+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (1.7ms)
2014-07-01T06:51:00.164009+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (6.6ms)
2014-07-01T06:51:00.165306+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.7ms)
2014-07-01T06:51:00.152352+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
2014-07-01T06:51:00.165745+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 13ms (Views: 10.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-07-01T06:51:01.519186+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users/sign_in" host=omr-photoshare.herokuapp.com request_id=2e71a5f1-e10a-4158-af5c-6f80f8aac4a3 fwd="65.78.4.236" dyno=web.1 connect=9ms service=144ms status=302 bytes=1041
2014-07-01T06:51:01.575579+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=omr-photoshare.herokuapp.com request_id=304d9c4f-d607-4f37-aa75-bf07c48ace45 fwd="65.78.4.236" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=25ms status=200 bytes=2911
2014-07-01T06:51:01.571496+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2014-07-01T06:51:01.518046+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 133ms (ActiveRecord: 12.5ms)
2014-07-01T06:51:01.381342+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 65.78.4.236 at 2014-07-01 06:51:01 +0000
2014-07-01T06:51:01.576450+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.5ms)
2014-07-01T06:51:01.384466+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
2014-07-01T06:51:01.384511+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+8dZCduvFyzofV4G28jmxjsOXYrweHJ+cdJe3lEWPTQ=", "user"=>{"email"=>"cghazanfar10@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
2014-07-01T06:51:01.517874+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://omr-photoshare.herokuapp.com/
2014-07-01T06:51:01.568980+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 65.78.4.236 at 2014-07-01 06:51:01 +0000
2014-07-01T06:51:01.575119+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (2.4ms)
2014-07-01T06:51:01.576943+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 3.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
2014-07-01T07:53:44.045215+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2014-07-01T07:53:44.044809+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2014-07-01T07:53:47.433692+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-07-01 07:53:47] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2014-07-01T07:53:47.433697+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2014-07-01T07:53:47.433700+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2014-07-01T07:53:47.433702+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2014-07-01T07:53:47.433704+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2014-07-01T07:53:47.433753+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
2014-07-01T07:53:47.433755+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
2014-07-01T07:53:47.433757+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
2014-07-01T07:53:47.433758+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
2014-07-01T07:53:47.433760+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2014-07-01T07:53:47.433761+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2014-07-01T07:53:47.433763+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2014-07-01T07:53:47.433764+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2014-07-01T07:53:47.433766+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `require'
2014-07-01T07:53:47.433767+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2014-07-01T07:53:47.433773+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-07-01 07:53:47] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2014-07-01T07:53:47.433817+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-07-01 07:53:47] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2014-07-01T07:53:47.433890+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-07-01T07:53:49.611381+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2014-07-01T07:53:46.855962+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2014-07-01T15:33:01.545336+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2014-07-01T15:33:01.545628+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2014-07-01T15:33:08.727524+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-07-01 15:33:08] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2014-07-01T15:33:08.727547+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-07-01 15:33:08] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2014-05-08) [x86_64-linux]
2014-07-01T15:33:08.727961+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-07-01 15:33:08] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=36532
2014-07-01T15:33:04.638475+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 36532 -e production`
2014-07-01T15:33:09.317544+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2014-07-01T15:33:10.624767+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=omr-photoshare.herokuapp.com request_id=10c1d02a-1e17-4a48-9838-c35c2d530b52 fwd="66.249.83.39" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=228
2014-07-01T16:38:20.572132+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2014-07-01T16:38:20.571809+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2014-07-01T16:38:25.614240+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-07-01 16:38:25] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2014-07-01T16:38:25.614249+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2014-07-01T16:38:25.614252+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2014-07-01T16:38:25.614254+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2014-07-01T16:38:25.614255+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2014-07-01T16:38:25.614257+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
2014-07-01T16:38:25.614260+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
2014-07-01T16:38:25.614258+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
2014-07-01T16:38:25.614262+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
2014-07-01T16:38:25.614268+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2014-07-01T16:38:25.614263+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2014-07-01T16:38:25.614342+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-07-01 16:38:25] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2014-07-01T16:38:25.614455+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-07-01T16:38:25.614272+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2014-07-01T16:38:25.614452+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2014-07-01T16:38:25.614265+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2014-07-01T16:38:25.614266+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2014-07-01T16:38:25.614270+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `require'
2014-07-01T16:38:25.614406+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-07-01 16:38:25] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2014-07-01T16:38:25.614450+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.1.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:36532
2014-07-01T16:38:25.614475+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-07-01T16:38:25.614448+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2014-07-01T16:38:25.614453+00:00 app[web.1]: => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
2014-07-01T16:38:24.918023+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2014-07-01T16:38:28.512103+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
```

I looked at some of the answers to this problem. Most of the people are saying that **Heroku** doesn't support **sqlite3** and that I need to convert my database to **PostgreSQL**

Additional Information:

**Gemfile**

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'

group :development, :test do
     gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
     gem 'pg'
     gem 'rails_12factor'
end

gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development
```

**config/database.yml**

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3


test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Thank you for any future help...

Comment: Try Restarting your Heroku App `heroku restart -a app_name`. Normally you don't have to configure your PG Database further on heroku (For OMR until now). Check for Migration's and if needed, because you are on a course you can drop and create your DB again.

Comment: Tried that already but still getting the same error page.

Comment: could you post your github repo from which you are pushing to heroku ?

Comment: Yes, here it is : https://github.com/cyzanfar/Photoshare

Comment: Your gemfile isn't updated !

Comment: How can I update them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**DB**

Your problem is almost certainly DB related (as you've already suggested)

Heroku has two types of error - the standard "Rails" errors & Heroku platform errors:

*Rails Error*

[image]

*Heroku Error*

[image]

--

**Error**

These errors are standard for Rails apps running on Heroku - the difference is the Rails error is one derived from the Rails app itself; the Heroku error is raised from the Heroku platform

Heroku errors essentially mean your application cannot load for some reason; typically because it's unable to connect to your DB, or the DB doesn't have the right data tables.

To fix this, you first need to ensure you're using a [database in production](http://robmclarty.com/blog/how-to-setup-a-production-server-for-rails-4) (Heroku's [Postgres DB](https://addons.heroku.com/heroku-postgresql) highly recommended):

```
#config/database.yml
production:
  ....
```

After you have this set up & pushed to `Heroku`, you then need to ensure the db is populated with the right tables. To do this, run `heroku run rake db:migrate` in your local `cmd`

---

**Update**

The way to make sure you have a production db is to use the [Heroku Postgres db](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-heroku-postgres-databases-from-outside-of-heroku), which should come as standard in your Heroku app dashboard

If you need to add the Heroku postgres db to your dashboard, you just need to [add the `add-on` here](https://addons.heroku.com/heroku-postgresql)

Once the db is in your dashboard, click on it & it should come up with the Postgres interface. You can see [how to connect to the db in Ruby here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-ruby); you should use the details provided by the Postgress add-on in your app's dashboard

Typically, a Heroku-compatible `database.yml` would look like this:

```
#config/database.yml
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: *********
  pool: 5
  username: *********    #-> *** data from heroku's postgres user details page
  password: ******
  host: ******
```

Comment: I am not sure how I should modify my config/database.yml file. Could you develop a bit more on that?

Comment: Zauzaj has posted what you need to include in the file itself; in regards to the content - you can get your database details from Heroku. I can write about it a little more if you're specific?

Comment: Ok, @zauzaj wrote `production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: your_database_name
  pool: 5
  username: postgres_username
  password: postgres_password
  host: 127.0.0.1`. however I do not know my database name and username/password. I'm following a tutorial online, we haven't played around with any db yet.

Comment: Okay my apologies - I meant the *structure* what you put in the production part is what he wrote. In terms of the actual data, the best way is to get a Heroku Postgres DB & use that. I can guide you through that process if you want?

Comment: I see, and yes please guide me through the process.

Comment: Awesome. I pushed my rails app using `git push heroku master` and now it works. I don't get the "application error" page anymore. Thanks mate!!

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to resolve this is to make production group in your Gemfile :

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Then in your terminal (in project path) run:

```
bundle install
```

After your bundle is successful, you need to change your config/database.yml file :

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: your_database_name
  pool: 5
  username: postgres_username
  password: postgres_password
  host: 127.0.0.1
```

This should to resolve your problem with changing database adapter.
PS. Take care about indentation in database.yml file, it's important.

Answer (score 2):

You have to modify your Gemfile, [Heroku doesn't like SQLite](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3)

```
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'


group :development, :test do
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

You can always, for reference, look at the [One Month Rails Github Repo](https://github.com/onemonthrails/pinteresting).